# How to uninstall application by coding without using UninstallActivity in android

Tags: android

is this possible to uninstall application without using uninstallerActivity.... I want to create my own uninstaller. is PackageManager is responsible for deleting a package then whats the method?

Comment: Well Shweta to my knowledge there is no such way to do silent uninstallation of an app.BTW for other way round ACTION_DELETE is the way to start the uninstaller activity for an app.

Comment: Thanks! But i think if we will delete .apk file then it may b possible but the problem is how can we get access to delete .apk file by code.